# Dropdownlist to Filter GridView

Tags: c#, gridview, drop-down-menu

I have tried different examples to filter a gridview by dropdownlist, but is it possible in a button on_click event?  Do i create something like a SelectedItem on each dropdown and have them added to the button event?  Sorry to be so vague....I would like to have the dropdowns with a selectedvalue and then add them together to perform a filter based on the returning results.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry to be so vague....I would like to have the dropdowns with a selectedvalue and then add them together to perform a filter based on the returning results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems a bit vague, but if I'm interpreting correctly you want a couple dropdownlists and a button.  The filtering shouldn't happen until the button is pressed.

Yes, you should be able to put code in the button_click event that references the SelectedItem(s) or SelectedValue(s) of the dropdowns and then builds and expression which can be used to set the RowFilter of the GridView.